# What is the meant by 'thread safe' object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I have used generic queue in C# collection and everyone says that it is better to use the object of System.Collection.Generic.Queue because of thread safety.

Please advise on the right decision to use Queue object, and how it is thread safe?

Answer (score 31):

"Thread safe" is a bit of an unfortunate term because it doesn't really have a solid definition. Basically it means that certain operations on the object are guaranteed to behave sensibly when the object is being operated on via multiple threads.

Consider the simplest example: a counter. Suppose you have two threads that are incrementing a counter. If the sequence of events goes:

- Thread one reads from counter, gets
  zero.
- Thread two reads from counter, gets
  zero.
- Thread one increments zero, writes
  one to counter.
- Thread two increments zero, writes
  one to counter.

Then notice how the counter has "lost" one of the increments. Simple increment operations on counters are not threadsafe; to make them threadsafe you can use locks, or InterlockedIncrement.

Similarly with queues. Not-threadsafe-queues can "lose" enqueues the same way that not-threadsafe counters can lose increments. Worse, not threadsafe queues can even crash or produce crazy results if you use them in a multi-threaded scenario improperly.

The difficulty with "thread safe" is that it is not clearly defined. Does it simply mean "will not crash"? Does it mean that sensible results will be produced? For example, suppose you have a "threadsafe" collection. Is this code correct?

```
if (!collection.IsEmpty) Console.WriteLine(collection[0]);
```

No. Even if the collection is "threadsafe", that doesn't mean that this code is correct; another thread could have made the collection empty after the check but before the writeline and therefore this code could crash, even if the object is allegedly "threadsafe". Actually determining that *every relevant combination* of operations is threadsafe is an extremely difficult problem.

Now to come to your actual situation: anyone who is telling you "you should use the Queue class, it is better because it is threadsafe" probably does not have a clear idea of what they're talking about. First off, Queue is not threadsafe. Second, whether Queue is threadsafe or not is completely irrelevant if you are only using the object on a single thread! If you have a collection that is going to be accessed on multiple threads, then, as I indicated in my example above, you have an extremely difficult problem to solve, regardless of whether the collection itself is "threadsafe". You have to determine that *every combination of operations* you perform on the collection is also threadsafe. This is a very difficult problem, and if it is one you face, then you should use the services of an expert on this difficult topic.

Comment: +1 For the solid expert testimony.  You are also right to point out that "thread safe" is a rather fuzzy concept.

Comment: I like how every thread-safety related question are answered by the same dude, which I've been reading from for about 2 hours now.

Comment: This is what the hardware lock instruction is for. Only one core can have the cache line for the duration of the whole RMW operation. The first core that requests the L3 cache slice for the lock is approved which causes it to send invalidates to other cores, and until it is unlocked by the core, other cores cannot RFO (I think it NAKs the requests. Vague memory from the manual)

Comment: Also why are other answers saying concurrency. It's parallelism

Answer (score 5):

A type that is thread safe can be safely accessed from multiple threads without concern for concurrency.  This usually means that the type is read-only.

Interestingly enough, `Queue<T>` is *not* thread safe - it can support concurrent reads as long as the queue isn't modified but that isn't the same thing as thread safety.

In order to think about thread safety consider what would happen if two threads were accessing a `Queue<T>` and a third thread came along and began either adding to or removing from this `Queue<T>`.  Since this type does not restrict this behavior it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

In dealing with multithreading, you usually have to deal with concurrency issues. The term "concurrency issues" refers to issues that are specifically introduced by the possibility of interleaving instructions from two different execution contexts on a resource shared by both. Here, in terms of thread safety, the execution contexts are two threads within a process; however, in related subjects they might be processes.

Thread safety measures are put in place to achieve two goals primarily. First is to regain determinism with regard to what happens if the threads context-switch (which is otherwise controlled by the OS and thus basically nondeterministic in user-level programs), to prevent certain tasks from being left half-finished or two contexts writing to the same location in memory one after the other. Most measures simply use a little bit of hardware-supported [test-and-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) instructions and the like, as well as software-level [synchronization constructs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Process_synchronization) to force all other execution contexts to stay away from a data type while another one is doing work that should not be interrupted.

Usually, objects that are read-only are thread-safe. Many objects that are not read-only are able to have data accesses (read-only) occur with multiple threads without issue, if the object is not modified in the middle. But this is not thread safety. Thread safety is when all manner of things are done to a data type to prevent any modifications to it by one thread from causing data corruption or deadlock even when dealing with many concurrent reads and writes.